# Inequality that is used to bound the number of walks of length $l$ that avoid $C$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, graph-theory

I am studying the proof of Theorem 9.2.7 from the probabilistic method (Alon-Spencer). Need some help for the following: Let $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$, where $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2=1$. Suppose $c_1^2 \le 1-c$, for some $0<c<1$ and let $\lambda_1=d$. If $\lambda_i \le \lambda$ for $i \in \{2,\dots,n\}$, then we want to show that $\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2\lambda_i \le (1-c)d+c\lambda$.

I have tried to break the sum in two parts as: $c_1^2\lambda_1+\sum_{i=2}^nc_i^2\lambda_i$. Using this we get the first part of the bound but not the second. We can easily show that $\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2\lambda_i \le (1-c)d+\lambda$, but this is much weaker upper bound that the one claimed in the theorem.

How do we get the bound claimed above (which is the bound in the theorem)?

Comment: You didn't really say what are the $\lambda$'s. Are they the eigenvalues of  an adjacency matrix?

Comment: Yes, they are eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix. The largest one is $d$ and all the other eigenvalues are at most $\lambda$.

Comment: Also, your question is very much unrelated to your title. There is no mention of walks in a graph in your actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am missing something the reasoning is as follows.

$$ \begin{align} c_1^2\lambda_1+\sum_{i=2}^nc_i^2\lambda_i &\leq c_1^2 d + \sum_{i=2}^nc_i^2\lambda \\ 
&= c_1^2 d + (1-c_1^2)\lambda 
\\ &= c_1^2(d-\lambda)+\lambda
\\ &\leq  (1-c)(d-\lambda)+\lambda
\\ &=(1-c)d+c\lambda. \end{align}$$